# How to free memory in C# that is allocated in C++

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, dll, memory-leaks

I have a C++ dll which is reading video frames from a camera.  These frames get allocated in the DLL returned via pointer to the caller (a C# program).

When C# is done with a particular frame of video, it needs to clean it up.   The DLL interface and memory management is wrapped in a disposable class in C# so its easier to control things.   However, it seems like the memory doesn't get freed/released.   The memory footprint of my process grows and grows and in less than a minute, I get allocation errors in the C++ DLL as there isn't any memory left.

The video frames are a bit over 9 MB each.   There is a lot of code, so I'll simply provide the allocation/deallocations/types/etc.

First : Allocation in C++ of raw buffer for the camera bytes.

```
dst = new unsigned char[mFrameLengthInBytes];
```

Second : transfer from the raw pointer back to across the DLL boundary as an unsigned char * and into an IntPtr in C#

```
IntPtr pFrame = VideoSource_GetFrame(mCamera, ImageFormat.BAYER);
return new VideoFrame(pFrame, .... );
```

So now the IntPtr is passed into the CTOR of the VideoFrame class.  Inside the CTOR the IntPtr is copied to an internal member of the class as follows :

```
IntPtr dataPtr;
public VideoFrame(IntPtr pDataToCopy, ...)
{
    ...
    this.dataPtr = pDataToCopy;
}
```

My understanding is that is a shallow copy and the class now references the original data buffer.    The frame is used/processed/etc.   Later, the VideoFrame class is disposed and the following is used to clean up the memory.

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(this.dataPtr);
```

I suspect the problem is that... dataPtr is an IntPtr and C# has no way to know that the underlying buffer is actually 9 MB, right?    Is there a way to tell it how much memory to release at that point?   Am I using the wrong C# free method?   Is there one specifically for this sort of situation?

Comment: VideoSource_ReleaseFrame(pFrame) ?

Comment: If memory is allocated in C++ dll then it should be freed there too.

Comment: The API doesn't have that sort of call.  Its all reuse code and was developed originally for use in other C++ programs so you could do a delete [] and get rid of the memory.   I can't change the interface but I can alter the code.   If there isn't a way to do in c# I'll have to do a workaround in c++.

Comment: @LawfulEvil `The API doesn't have that sort of call` Well that's a huge gap. There are a myriad number of ways that memory can be allocated, each with their own matching deallocation function. Also, unless you want to get into more issues, the DLL should be deallocating the memory, since it knows how it allocated the memory, plus the DLL is working on the same heap, not a (potentially) different heap that the C# module is using.

Comment: Tell me about it.   The boss is all about reuse and says I can just grab this is go and not budget any new development time because it just all works out of the box.    Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LawfulEvil The only way out is if the C++ DLL used one of the Windows API heap allocation functions (HeapAlloc, GlobalAlloc, etc.) to allocate the memory.  Then you could call the corresponding Windows deallocation function in C# (using pinvoke).  But that would be the only "safe" way of doing this.  Otherwise, you're stuck -- you need a function in the C++ DLL to deallocate the memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call the corresponding "free" method in the library you're using.

Memory allocated via `new` is part of the C++ runtime, and calling `FreeHGlobal` won't work. You need to call (one way or the other) `delete[]` against the memory.

If this is your own library then create a function (eg `VideoSource_FreeFrame`) that deletes the memory. Eg:

```
void VideoSource_FreeFrame(unsigned char *buffer)
{
  delete[] buffer;
}
```

And then call this from C#, passing in the `IntPtr` you got back.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the use of delegates in C++ but would it be possible to wrap the allocation and deallocation in a single function with a callback delegate to the C# to do something with the data before it gets deallocated?  It would be more consumer-friendly if it were able to be just a single call instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to (in c++) `delete dst;`. That means you need to provide an API that the C# code can call, like `FreeFrame(...)`, which does exactly that.

Comment: In my case, its delete [], but yes, it seems I need to get buy in from the other stake holders and update the API, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first answer. Do NOT free it in C# code, using any magical, liturgical incantations. Write a method in C++ that free's the memory, and call it from your C# code. Do NOT get into the habit of allocationg memory in one heap (native) and freeing it another heap (managed), that's just bad news.

Remember one of the rules from the book effective C++: Allocate memory in the constructor, and deallocate in the destructor. And if you can't do it in the destructor, do it in an in-class method, not some global (or even worse) friend function.